# Connection to my full node via Python script suddenly fails

Tags: full-node, connection, request

I run a mynode full node on a raspi for quite some time now and was playing around with Python scripts to connect and send txs. This worked fine until lately. Turns out the connection establish process fails because my full node refuses the connection request I send from my PC.
Apparently, he's not fine with me connecting via port 8333 which I always did in the past. Why would the request be rejected? Both, full node and PC are in the same VLAN.
Below a photo link from wireshark to a connection request with port 8333 (fails) and a request with port 8332 (no issues).

https://postimg.cc/gallery/7ZwCxDH (server responds to TCP handshake with a TCP reset (RST))

The relevant code block comes down to:

```
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    HOST = "192.168.30.87" 
    PORT = 8333  
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

The full node is fully synced with plenty of connections (Tor and Non-Tor).

Below the result from `netstat -tulp` (updated with admin rights to show the program using the socket):

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:amanda          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25329/lnd           
tcp        0      0 localhost:xtell         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5398/electrs        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9824            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 localhost:7656          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/i2pd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62602           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3559/redis-server 1 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28332           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8332            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 localhost:6668          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/i2pd            
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:8333         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 localhost:8333          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28333           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8013            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 localhost:8334          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5037/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28334           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3846/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8335            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7928/node           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2223            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8015            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7295/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      729/python3         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9136            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/i2pd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5398/electrs        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2225            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8017            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49393           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50002           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8019            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      759/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61208           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      733/python3.8       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10009           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25329/lnd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8089            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61209           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8432/node           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8890            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 localhost:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3178/tor            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:https           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 localhost:9051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3178/tor            
tcp        0      0 localhost:4444          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/i2pd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5021            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3341/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 localhost:7070          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/i2pd            
tcp        0      0 localhost:4447          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/i2pd            
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      759/sshd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51194           0.0.0.0:*                           1920/openvpn        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                           1516/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9136            0.0.0.0:*                           785/i2pd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                           595/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 localhost:7655          0.0.0.0:*                           785/i2pd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42496           0.0.0.0:*                           595/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 [::]:44900              [::]:*                              595/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                              595/avahi-daemon: r
```

I only see `localhost` and `172.17.0.1` with port 8333, so thats odd.

In the `bitcoin.conf` I explicitly added the IP of my client PC to the whitelist (192.168.30.156)

```
# bitcoin configuration
# /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

# Bitcoin options
server=1
daemon=1

# Bind to localhost and docker
bind=127.0.0.1
bind=172.17.0.1

# Needed for BTC-RPC-Explorer
txindex=1

# CPU count
par=-1

# Debug log settings
shrinkdebugfile=1

# Connection settings
rpcauth=mynode:ac633d1117f36eb0d44651f76e2f4b13$ccb595afbb45b19718ae3870715f39f8dc7dbcaa137c5ffd969f47e47fbade13

rpcport=8332
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=10.0.0.0/8
rpcallowip=172.16.0.0/12
rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/16

# Set default wallet so some wallet APIs work
main.wallet=wallet.dat
main.wallet=joinmarket_wallet.dat

test.wallet=wallet.dat
test.wallet=joinmarket_wallet.dat

# Enable Deprecated RPCs
deprecatedrpc=addresses

# Whitelist local connections (and docker)
whitelist=127.0.0.1
whitelist=192.168.30.156
whitelist=172.16.0.0/12

# Dont limit data to electrum server or local network
whitelist=download@10.0.0.0/8
whitelist=download@192.168.0.0/16

# Enable Bloom filters (local network)
whitelist=bloomfilter@10.0.0.0/8
whitelist=bloomfilter@192.168.0.0/16

zmqpubrawblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://0.0.0.0:28333
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28334

# myNode Optimizations
dbcache=1000
maxorphantx=10
maxmempool=250
maxconnections=40
maxuploadtarget=1000
rpcworkqueue=32

# IPv4 Disabled
dnsseed=0
dns=0

# Tor config
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
listen=1
#onlynet=onion
```

Update:

So I checked with `nmap` and the port is closed:

```
admin@myNode:~ $ nmap 192.168.30.87 -p 8333
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-11-24 01:42 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.30.87
Host is up (0.0090s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8333/tcp closed bitcoin
```

However using the `ufw` command it returns the port is already open. Any hints?

Update: below the `ifconfig` result:

```
admin@myNode:~ $ ifconfig -a
br-0b53e988a5ad: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.28.255.255
        ether 02:42:a4:07:0d:c1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-64d06c0adaf9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.26.0.255
        ether 02:42:f3:41:f8:72  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8998434  bytes 819555438 (781.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9009649  bytes 36218286954 (33.7 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-68444510781f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        ether 02:42:6e:7b:52:df  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-85aa3cb4cfcd: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255
        ether 02:42:22:1b:53:1a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-f1547965b042: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:77:f6:03:a1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1334303  bytes 101434833 (96.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2113575  bytes 1022268903 (974.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:f9:d8:80:7b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5154  bytes 732024 (714.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6071  bytes 2700322 (2.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.30.87  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.30.255
        inet6 fe80::4690:abb5:3d80:5b6b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:77:11:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7749728  bytes 3536205167 (3.2 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9660173  bytes 8853888597 (8.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 68625988  bytes 17225478612 (16.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68625988  bytes 17225478612 (16.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth1693a12: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 76:3b:3f:ab:62:62  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1024704  bytes 109773777 (104.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1103554  bytes 1164128434 (1.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth2066f12: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 66:21:35:37:84:83  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13803  bytes 11002093 (10.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14065  bytes 5219579 (4.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth7961b83: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8a:c8:c4:b0:d3:85  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2437851  bytes 1284242989 (1.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3138277  bytes 1132042455 (1.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth930bbd0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 72:86:21:2b:cb:75  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9004689  bytes 950162045 (906.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9015339  bytes 36228912911 (33.7 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethc1bb991: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 5e:a3:21:cc:f6:a8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36284  bytes 3813244 (3.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 36602  bytes 3599357 (3.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethdff0d05: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4e:1e:fe:e0:93:e2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5154  bytes 804180 (785.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6071  bytes 2700322 (2.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:77:11:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Update: I checked the firewall rules:

```
admin@myNode:~ $ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 8889                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow lndg HTTP
[ 2] 25441                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Specter Desktop
[ 3] 8890                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow lndg HTTPS
[ 4] 49392                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow BTCPay Server-direct
[ 5] 2224                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow wetty HTTP
[ 6] 49393                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow BTCPay Server-direct HTTPS
[ 7] 2225                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow wetty HTTPS
[ 8] 51194                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow VPN
[ 9] 61208                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Glances
[10] 61209                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Glances HTTPS
[11] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1                  # allow from localhost
[12] 19999                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow netdata HTTP
[13] 20000                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow netdata HTTPS
[14] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow SSH
[15] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow WWW
[16] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Secure WWW
[17] 1900                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow SSDP for UPnP discovery
[18] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    10.0.0.0/8 1900            # allow UPnP from router
[19] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/16 1900        # allow UPnP from router
[20] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    172.16.0.0/12 1900         # allow UPnP from router
[21] 9911                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Lightning Watchtower
[22] 10009                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Lightning gRPC
[23] 10080                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Lightning REST RPC
[24] 9735                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Lightning
[25] 8332                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Bitcoin RPC - filtered by rpcallowip
[26] 8333                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[27] 18333                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Bitcoin testnet
[28] 28332                      ALLOW IN    172.17.0.0/16              # allow Dojo zmqrawblock
[29] 28332                      ALLOW IN    172.28.0.0/16              # allow Dojo zmqrawblock
[30] 28333                      ALLOW IN    172.17.0.0/16              # allow Dojo zmqrawtx
[31] 28333                      ALLOW IN    172.28.0.0/16              # allow Dojo zmqrawtx
[32] 28334                      ALLOW IN    172.17.0.0/16              # allow Dojo zmqhashblock
[33] 28334                      ALLOW IN    172.28.0.0/16              # allow Dojo zmqhashblock
[34] 8335                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow corsproxy for btc rpc
[35] 8443                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Lightning Terminal
[36] 2222                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow WebSSH2
[37] 2223                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow WebSSH2 HTTPS
[38] 3000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow LndHub
[39] 3001                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow LndHub HTTPS
[40] 3002                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow BTC RPC Explorer
[41] 3003                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow BTC RPC Explorer HTTPS
[42] 3010                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow RTL
[43] 3011                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow RTL HTTPS
[44] 3020                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Caravan
[45] 3030                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Thunderhub
[46] 3031                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Thunderhub HTTPS
[47] 3493                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Network UPS Tools
[48] 4080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Mempool
[49] 4081                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Mempool HTTPS
[50] 5000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow LNBits
[51] 5001                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow LNBits HTTPS
[52] 5010                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Warden Terminal
[53] 5011                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Warden Terminal HTTPS
[54] 5353                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Avahi
[55] 8010:8019/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow USB Extras HTTP/HTTPS
[56] 8899                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Whirlpool
[57] 9823                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow CKBunker
[58] 9824                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow CKBunker HTTPS
[59] 50001                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Electrum Server
[60] 50002                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Electrum Server
[61] 53001                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow Sphinx Relay
[62] 56881                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow myNode QuickSync
[63] 51413                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow myNode QuickSync
[64] 6771                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow myNode QuickSync (LPD)
[65] 2189                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow UPnP
[66] 5351                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow NAT-PMP
[67] 5020                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow jam HTTP
[68] 5021                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow jam HTTPS
[69] 5030                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow lilywallet HTTP
[70] 5031                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow lilywallet HTTPS
[71] 8088                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow tailscale HTTP
[72] 8089                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow tailscale HTTPS
[73] 62601                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow JoinMarket Orderbook
[74] 62602                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow JoinMarket Orderbook HTTPS
[75] 27183                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow JoinMarket API
[76] 28183                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # allow JoinMarket API
```

There's the port 8333 but it doesn't seem to be associated with Bitcoin. I assume it's listed because I opend it manually. So is the full node not using port 8333 at all?

Comment: Are you sure the Raspberry Pi  node is configured to listen on 8333? What is in it's `bitcoin.conf` or equivalent? What shows up in `netstat -tulp` on the Pi?

Comment: Thanks, I added the results to the post. I guess I miss a `0.0.0.0:8333` ?

Comment: So I checked with `nmap` and the port is closed:

`admin@myNode:~ $ nmap 192.168.30.87 -p 8333
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-11-24 01:42 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.30.87
Host is up (0.0090s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8333/tcp closed bitcoin`
Using the `ufw` command it returns the port is already open. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pi either has multiple Ethernet interfaces or, more likely, IP aliases - it has two external IP addresses and the bitcoin service is only bound to the 172 address not the 192 address.

The command `ifconfig -a might clarify this.

I also think the netmask in your `rpcallowip=172.16.0.0/12` might not allow for 172.17 as that differs in bit 16:which is outside the 12 bit range specified?

The p option on the netstat command should show the process name but maybe that depends on being run with root permissions.

I believe restarting Bitcoind after sorting out the IP addressing in the pi, or at least  configuring Bitcoind to bind to the 192 address, should resolve the problem.

Try adding

```
bind=192.168.30.87
```

To your `bitcoin.conf` and restart Bitcoind.

Comment: See attached the `ifconfig` results. Not sure if that supports your assumption?

Comment: Regarding the `rpcallowip=172.16.0.0/12` you're probably right, however shouldn't affect the node access via port 8333? (rpc is port 8332)
The updated `netstat -tulp` shows that bitcoind does not use a socket with the 192 address. 
I clearly lack understanding, but for me that would have been the socket to communicate with all the other ip4 nodes I'm connected to....apparently the full node does that differently.

Comment: Try adding the bind directive I added to my answer. I assume you know how to stop and restart bitcoind

Comment: Thanks, adding the bind directive seems to be sufficent, I can now connect via 192.168.30.87:8333
You see any advantage to restart bitcoind? Does it affect the snycd blockchain?